# Next JS, unable to update user info in prism database

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

Background:

- I've created a schema using Prism and I want to update the orgName in my table via a form.

**schema.prisma**

```
model User {
  id                 String    @id @default(cuid())
  name               String?
  email              String?   @unique()
  emailVerified      DateTime?
  image              String?
  orgImage           String?
  accounts           Account[]
  sessions           Session[]
  orgName            String?
  lastFourCC         String?
  acctType           String?
  subscriptionExpiry DateTime?
}
```

- I've created a route: localhost:3000/api/update and have hard coded the values of my email (since I am logged in with my Google account via next-auth) and a test org name

**update.js**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const { email, orgName } = req.body;
  console.log("req body", email);
  try {
    const addOrg = await prisma.user.update({
      where: {
         email: "somename.co@gmail.com"
      },
      data: {
        orgName: "Some Company"
      },
    });
    console.log("data", email);
    res.status(200).json(addOrg);
    console.log("addOrg", addOrg);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: `Something went wrong :/ ${error}`,
    });
  }
}
```

- In Postman, I send test my PUT request, which returns the correct data including the hardcoded values for email & username.

**POSTMAN REQUEST**

```
    "id": "cl7okriae001fs0sfalag8exe",
    "name": "Jon Jones",
    "email": "somename@gmail.com",
    "emailVerified": null,
    "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/.....vFX0A=s96-c",
    "orgImage": null,
    "orgName": "Some Company",
    "lastFourCC": null,
    "acctType": null,
    "subscriptionExpiry": null
```

Now I am trying to send data from my form to update this user:

**step2.js**

```
const Step2 = () => {
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const updateUserInfo = async (data) => {
    try {
      await ("http://localhost:3000/api/update",
      {
        body: JSON.stringify(),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "PUT",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new error();
    }
    console.log("Update User Info", data);
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log("onSubmit Info", data);
    try {
      toast.promise(
        updateUserInfo(data),
        {
          loading: "Working on it...",
          success: "Feedback submitted successfully!",
          error: "Oops! something went wrong.",
        },
        {
          duration: 3000,
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="orgName"
        placeholder="Spacely Sprockets LLC"
        className="inputAreaFull"
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button className="generalButton" type="submit">
        Continue
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

After updating **update.js** with the following info....

```
      where: {
         email: email
      },
      data: {
        orgName: orgName
      },
    });
```

...in the browser, when I submit my info, I get the toast notification that my request was submitted successfully. However, checking Prism Studio, the record has not been updated.
When I send the PUT request to postman, I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Something went wrong :/ Error: \nInvalid `prisma.user.update()` invocation:\n\n{\n  where: {\n?   email?: String,\n?   id?: String\n  },\n  data: {\n    orgName: undefined\n  }\n}\n\nArgument where of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.\n\nNote: Lines with ? are optional.\n"
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the error. I am using the email address as the unique argument but I cannot get past this point.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty helpful in understanding what went wrong:

```
Argument where of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument
```

You're passing in `email` as an argument to the `prisma.user.update` operation, but the `email` variable is `undefined`. You can confirm this by adding `console.log(email)` somewhere in your API route (before the `prisma.user.update` call.)

I noticed two things in your original code:

1. You never actually make a `fetch` call (maybe you do and the code in your post just isn't updated, but your original code omits a `fetch`)
2. Your `body` parameter to what I assume is the fetch call actually omits the body - `body: JSON.stringify()` is what's being passed to the `fetch` call, and I think you meant to do `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Your code should end up looking like this:

```js
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/update", {
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```